# Phpmyadmin Access denied

Tags: server, apache2, php, mysql

When I go on `localhost/phpmyadmin` it returns me this :

> Cannot connect: invalid settings.
>   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I had some issues with phpmyadmin before so I uninstalled it to reinstall it. But apparently it's worse now...

After a few search on the internet I saw that it could come from the file `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. 
But I don't have the folder phpmyadmin in `/etc` and even not in xampp

Thank you for your help...

Comment: I found it with the locate command it was in opt/lampp/ thanks...

Comment: The error is back --'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using xampp i would recommend to install the ApachePHPMySql thingy in ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

EDIT: The ubuntu phpmyadmin documentation is found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/phpmyadmin.html

Comment: Everybody is using Xampp why would that work everywhere else and not with me ?

Comment: Well i thought it is easier this way, plus you know how to set up your own server. Anyway, to your problem: I would recommend checking MySQL with the mysql client, see if the database, etc. for phpmyadmin exist and check if that matches your phpmyadmin config.